# How to serialize form data of iframe with Apify

Tags: puppeteer, apify

Ok,So I try to serialize a form data, but I get undefined
Here is code:

```
 const frame = page.frames().find(frame => frame.url().includes('reservation'));
const aHandle = await frame.evaluateHandle('document'); 
const form= await aHandle.$eval('#reservationData', element => element.outerHTML);
var theform = await serialize(form);
console.log(theform);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how the function serialize looks like. Can you provide code of this function?

But you can do it easily with `frame.$eval(selector, pageFunction[, ...args])` and jQuery.

```
const Apify = require('apify');

...

await Apify.utils.puppeteer.injectJQuery(page);
const frame = page.frames().find(frame => frame.url().includes('reservation'));
const theForm = frame.$eval('#reservationData', (form) => $(form).serialize())
console.log(theform);
```

Comment: No problem, happy to help!